# How to create a start and end date with no gaps from one date column and to sum a value within the dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sum, gaps-and-islands

I am new SQL coding using in SQL developer.

I have a table that has 4 columns: Patient ID (ptid), service date (dt), insurance payment amount (insr_amt), out of pocket payment amount (op_amt). (see table 1 below)

What I would like to do is (1) create two columns "start_dt" and "end_dt" using the "dt" column where if there are no gaps in the date by the patient ID then populate the start and end date with the first and last date by patient ID, however if there is a gap in service date within the patient ID then to create the separate start and end date rows per patient ID, along with (2) summing the two payment amounts by patient ID with in the one set of start and end date visits (see table 2 below).

What would be the way to run this using SQL code in SQL developer?
Thank you!

Table 1:

| Ptid | dt | insr_amt | op_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2021 | 30 | 20 |
| A | 1/2/2021 | 30 | 10 |
| A | 1/3/2021 | 30 | 10 |
| A | 1/4/2021 | 30 | 30 |
| B | 1/6/2021 | 10 | 10 |
| B | 1/7/2021 | 20 | 10 |
| C | 2/1/2021 | 15 | 30 |
| C | 2/2/2021 | 15 | 30 |
| C | 2/6/2021 | 60 | 30 |

Table 2:

| Ptid | start_dt | end_dt | total_insr_amt | total_op_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2021 | 1/4/2021 | 120 | 70 |
| B | 1/6/2021 | 1/7/2021 | 30 | 20 |
| C | 2/1/2021 | 2/2/2021 | 30 | 60 |
| C | 2/6/2021 | 2/6/2021 | 60 | 30 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the specific database so this solution works in PostgreSQL. You can do:

```
select
  ptid,
  min(dt) as start_dt,
  max(dt) as end_dt,
  sum(insr_amt) as total_insr_amt,
  sum(op_amt) as total_op_amt
from (
  select *,
    sum(inc) over(partition by ptid order by dt) as grp
  from (
    select *,
      case when dt - interval '1 day' = lag(dt) over(partition by ptid order by dt)
           then 0 else 1 end as inc
    from t
  ) x
) y
group by ptid, grp
order by ptid, grp
```

Result:

```
 ptid  start_dt    end_dt      total_insr_amt  total_op_amt 
 ----- ----------  ----------  --------------  ----------- 
 A     2021-01-01  2021-01-04  120             70           
 B     2021-01-06  2021-01-07  30              20           
 C     2021-02-01  2021-02-02  30              60           
 C     2021-02-06  2021-02-06  60              30
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle 1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kUBWR5hJN5vK4GCQUyDg2G/1).

**EDIT for Oracle**

As requested, the modified query that works in Oracle is:

```
select
  ptid,
  min(dt) as start_dt,
  max(dt) as end_dt,
  sum(insr_amt) as total_insr_amt,
  sum(op_amt) as total_op_amt
from (
  select x.*,
    sum(inc) over(partition by ptid order by dt) as grp
  from (
    select t.*,
      case when dt - 1 = lag(dt) over(partition by ptid order by dt)
           then 0 else 1 end as inc
    from t
  ) x
) y
group by ptid, grp
order by ptid, grp
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1d5306c518824fa7cb7e5e043a097419).

Comment: When I break apart the code and run each subquery one by one it works. But when I ran it as above it does not seem to like the grp variable in the order by expression. I get the error: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
01791. 00000 -  "not a SELECTed expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 18 Column: 18  here line 18 is "order by ptid, grp" and column 18 is grp. This is odd as if I run the sub queries independently then it works! Thank you!

Comment: You didn't specify the database so this example works in PostgreSQL.

Comment: See solution for Oracle database.

Comment: Thank you, yes it was for an Oracle database! edit worked! thank you